# Store Powershell result in SQL table

Tags: sql, powershell

Since I am new to Powershell I am looking for some assistance for my problem.

What I need is to count the number of files in a network folder and use that number for a Bulk-Insert loop. Currently, the number of loop cyles is stored in a "status-table" (in SQL). I want to be able to update that status table with the actual number of files.
The powershell cmdlet to count the number of files looks like this:

```
 $FileCount = @(Get-ChildItem -Path '\\YS001UVE\Download\MIS\MIS FactData 20??m?1.csv' -Name -File | sort Name).count
```

But then I need to update the existing "status-table" with the outcome of the Powershell script .
What is the correct SQL coding for this?

Thanks in advance and regards
Peter

Comment: See https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/update-excel-spreadsheets-powershell

Comment: any update? did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. [This Post](https://www.mysql.com/de/products/connector/) contains an example to do this task. For some database connections you may need to install something on your computer (for MySQL you need the [MySQL Connector](https://www.mysql.com/de/products/connector/)).

---

I've done this myself and know, how confusing it can be at first. Under this [link](https://github.com/Nicicalu/Datenbank-Script-M122/blob/master/script.ps1), you can find my script (sorry for the German comments and text). The database connection starts at about line 270 in the function `Import-ToDatabase`. Be aware that I am not updating one single line in my script, but a whole new table.

Let me know if you need some more help

---

Here are a few more links:

- https://www.joseespitia.com/2016/06/03/connecting-and-writing-to-a-sql-db-with-powershell/
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/insert-data-into-a-sql-server-table-using-powershell-using-invoke-sqlc
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/performing-an-insert-from-a-powershell-script